# Solve a ODE with specific conditions

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

I am trying to find (some) functions h(x,t) such that A h(b,t)+B h_x(b,t)=g(t), where A,B,b are constants and g(t) is a given function of time (h_x is the partial derivative w.r.t. the first component of h(x,t)).

I use this command first
DSolve[A h[x, t] + B D[h[x, t], x] == g[t], h[x, t], {x, t}]
that gives me h(x,t)=g(t)/A + k(t)*e^{-A/B x} such that A h(x,t)+B h_x(x,t)=g(t), which is true also for x=b of course, but I would prefer to have expressions for h(x,t) that satisfy the ODE only when evaluated at x=b (e.g. h(x,t)=g(t)/A + (x-b)^2).

So I tried to use this command
DSolve[A h[b, t] + B Derivative[1, 0][h][b, t] == g[t], h[x, t], {x, t}], but this apparently does not work.
Can someone please help me?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: This is an ordinary differential equation with respect to x of first order. It is inhomogeneous. Since g[t] is not dependent on x it is solve by a sum to the homogeneous solution. The function k[t] is free as a multiplicative function. So the solution is correct. There is in this caes another homogeneous de possible. D[h[x,t],x]==0 with the boundary condition h[b,t]==0. This is solved by k[t] too. Your function h[x,t] has h'[x,t]==x-b that is not zero for all x and t, despite it solves the boundary condition. A constant function would do too addinate to k[t].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is not a differential equation, but a boundary condition.  Without a PDE, the solution space is quite large and can be found by "algebraic" means without any integration.

```
eq = A h[b, t] + B Derivative[1, 0][h][b, t] == g[t]; 
a0 = Solve[eq, h[b, t]]
```

> ```
> (*  {{h[b, t] -> (g[t] - B*Derivative[1, 0][h][b, t])/A}}  *)
> ```

```
hEXPR = Normal@Series[h[x, t], {x, b, 2}] /. 
   First@a0 /. {Derivative[1, 0][h][b, t] :> h[1][t],
   Derivative[2, 0][h][b, t] :> h[2][x, t]}
hsol = {h -> Function[{x, t}, Evaluate@hEXPR]};
```

> ```
> (*  (-b + x) h[1][t] + (g[t] - B h[1][t])/A + 1/2 (-b + x)^2 h[2][x, t]  *)
> ```

```
eq /. hsol // Simplify
```

> ```
> (*  True  *)
> ```

The solution `hsol` is a general solution in which `h[1][t]` and `h[2][x, t]` are arbitrary functions (of whatever desired class of smoothness).

Comment: Truly excellent work, that was exactly what I was asking. You re right, in fact, the problem I am tackling is this boundary problem: h_t=1/2 sigma^2 x^2 h_xx +r x h_x  subject to that boundary condition I have stated before, where sigma, r are constants and h=h[x,t]. My idea was to find an h that satisfies the boundary and then find h[1][t] and h[2][x,t] in order to match the PDE. I was trying to use Dsolve to try to find h[1][t] and h[2][x,t], in order to satisfy the PDE but I don't know how to use that since I am quite new in using Mathematica. If you could help me I would be very thankful.

Comment: Basically, I got this boundary value problem  h_t=1/2 sigma^2 x^2 h_xx +r x h_x s.t. Ah(b,t)+Bh_x(b,t). I need an explicit solution for it,, whatever it is (I am able to get general semi-explicit solutions up to inversion of transforms, using Lie symmetries, but I need something easier to handle). Any solutions satisfing the PDE and the boundary condition will be fine.

Comment: Ah(b,t)+Bh_x(b,t)=g(t), sorry for the typo.